# Why does Crystal evaluates this as false?

Tags: crystal-lang

As practice, I want to make a function that returns the first index of a character in a string. The function takes two arguments, the string and the character to get the index of. I iterate over the string to match against the provided character. I'm printing the evaluation of each iteration for testing but it returns false even when they should be equal.

```
def index_of?(obj, el)
  unless obj.size == 0
    num = 0
    while num < obj.size
      puts "#{obj[num]} == #{el} : #{obj[num] == el}"
      num += 1
    end
  end
end

str = "hello"
index_of?(str, "h")
```

This prints:

```
h == h : false
e == h : false
l == h : false
l == h : false
o == h : false
```

Comment: Iterating through each character in a String with a counting index has bad performance and is actually discouraged. You should iterate over a `Char::Reader` instead: `obj.each_char_with_index { |char, i| return i if char == el }`.

Answer (score 7):

Because `obj[num]` returns a [Char](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/Char.html), not a String.

Doing `index_of?(str, 'h')` will print:

```
h == h : true
e == h : false
l == h : false
l == h : false
o == h : false
```